# GET request gets triggered instead of template render with AngularJS, Rails and ngModal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am using Rails, `angular-rails-templates` gem, Angular 1.4.8 and http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/.

My project structure keeps my template files in `app/assets/javascripts/templates` and my angular project in `app/assets/javascripts/angular-app`. I have set up ng-modal as:

```
$scope.callModal = function () {
      ngDialog.open({
          template: 'tickets/partials/_resolve.html',
          controller: 'TicketEditController',
          scope: $scope
     });
 };
```

I have a template called `_resolve.html.erb` inside my `app/assets/javascripts/templates/partials/_resolve.html.erb`. The issue is that whenever I press on the button who `ng-click` the function, I see a GET request to `/tickets/partials/_resolve.html` so it doesn't actual render the template but just makes an http request to that uri.

The modal pops up but displays the whole root page (not the template).

How can I make this work?

Comment: In the network tab of your console the http request for url "tickets/partials/_resolve.html" goes. Can you check whats the response of the request.

Comment: @Kushal it loads for a long time and then displays the whole site. I guess it's because it searches for /resolve url and the catch-all in my app.js sends it there.

Comment: I am guessing either the template url tha you have provided doenst exist or the template is missing on the server and thats why the server is returning you the index page instead

Comment: I usually declare partials with ng-include, so the templates doesn't have to exist as a url - they are rendered by Angular. In this case, it seems that ngModal doesn't render them as partials but instead it needs a url which doesn't make much sense. Should I abandon this Angular plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

try moving your html file to a directory `app/assets/templates/partials/_resolve.html`. Unless you have your templates configured differently than [angular rails templates](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates) suggests in their documentation

Comment: this is where my template resides.

Comment: in your question it resides in `/javascripts/`

Comment: I have about ~30 templates and the site is in production for the past month, so I suppose everything works ok.